# Rendering from string instead of a file

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

for my website I'm making an adaptive way of "notification", for that I need to render some html with {{ @something }}'s in it but from a variable, not from a file. How can I do this ?

EDIT: let's say i have this:

```
$text = "abc {{ @somevar }}";
```

If it (the `abc {{ @somevar }}`) would be inside a file, i would have done :

```
\Template::instance()->render('file.html');
```

But it's not a file, it's a string, how can I do that now ?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. Hydrating a template does not differ whether it comes from a file or a variable. It is a string in both cases.

Comment: doing `\Template::instance()->render('abc {{ @somevar }}');` won't do the trick, it tries to find a file named that way but there is none.

Comment: You did not consider what I mentioned above. Or you believe that the method `render()` in the template object is somehow magical. It is a method. You can look into it.  What does it do? It expects a filename, tries to read that file and then hydrate the content. So you need a method just like that, only that it hydrates the string handed over directly instead of interpreting it as a file name.

Comment: build() seems to do the job, thanks !

Comment: `build()` will produce the PHP code but not execute it. You're probably looking for [resolve()](http://fatfreeframework.com/preview#resolve).

Comment: Before looking at resolve() I did the exact same thing in my code